# c# Utilizar el valor de una variable string, para hacer referencia a campo X

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

soy muy novato en esto de la programación en C#, pido mis disculpas por no hablar con propiedad.

Gracias de antemano a tod@s.

Mi problema.
Tengo un Campo Imagen nombrado como campoImg, al pasar el raton por encima de la imagen, este campo lanza un MouseEnter, dentro Metodo capturo el nombre del campo y lo almaceno en una variable.

El objetivo es utilizar esa variable para hacer refencia a el campo desde el codigo de c# y cambiar la imagen que muestra por pantalla.

¿como puedo utilizar el contenido de la variable para utilizarlo en el codigo c#?
algo parecido a esto.

string miPicture = "campoImg";

miPicture.source = "./casa.png";

.

Mi objetivo seria que c# lo leyera como: campoImg.source = "./casa.png";

...

// // Añado comentario

Hola,
Actualmente tengo esto.

XAML

```
<Image x:Name="Mshutdown" Width="24" Height="24"
HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="./Iconos/shutdown_Off.png" 
MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Mhome_MouseLeave" />
```

c#

```
private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri resourceUri = new Uri("./Iconos/casa_On.png", UriKind.Relative);
            string origen = (sender as Image).Name;
            if (origen == "Mhome")
            { Mhome.Source = new BitmapImage(resourceUri); }
            else if(origen == "Mshutdown")
            { 
                resourceUri = new Uri("./Iconos/shutdown_On.png", UriKind.Relative);
                Mshutdown.Source = new BitmapImage(resourceUri);
            }
        }
```

Quiero:
en vez de "Mhome.Source" y "Mshutdown.Source" utilizar el contenido de la variable "origen"

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices "campo imagen" en realidad es un control Image, porque sino no entiendo de donde sale el evento. La variable va a contener la ruta al archivo que quieres mostrar? Podrias poner algo del codigo que usas actualmente para mostrar la imagen y como asocias el evento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema es que tienes varios controles `Image` pero usas el mismo evento para todas, entonces quieres saber su nombre para identificar cual llamó al evento y setear su `Source`... pues bien, te comento que usar su nombre como `String` para trabajar con ellas NO es la manera indicada, ya que los nombres no debes tratarlos como `String`, simplemente los escribes tal cual y el compilador los reconocerá, si los escribes como `string` entonces pasa a ser un valor cualquiera.

Lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto:

```
private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Uri resourceUri = new Uri(@"/Iconos/casa_On.png", UriKind.Relative);
    Image imagen = (Image)sender;
    string origen = imagen.Name; //INNECESARIO
    if (origen == "Mhome")
    {
        imagen.Source = new BitmapImage(resourceUri);
    }
    else if (origen == "Mshutdown")
    {
        resourceUri = new Uri(@"/Iconos/shutdown_On.png", UriKind.Relative);
        Mshutdown.Source = new BitmapImage(resourceUri);
    }
}
```

Pero es poco óptimo, lo ideal sería algo como lo siguiente, recuerda que puedes crear las `Uri` dentro del paréntesis de `BitmapImage` y con eso te ahorras una linea de código:

```
private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    Image imagen = (Image)sender;
    if (imagen.Name.Equals("Mhome"))
    {
        imagen.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Iconos/casa_On.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else if (imagen.Name.Equals("Mshutdown"))
    {
        imagen.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Iconos/shutdown_On.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Sin embargo ¿qué pasa si tienes 10 controles `Image`? harás 10 `if`? Mejor tratar este problema desde otra perspectiva, con `switch`, esto te permitirá mantener ordenado este tema:

```
private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch(((Image)sender).Name)
    {
        case "Mhome":
        ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Iconos/casa_On.png", UriKind.Relative));
        break;
        case "Mshutdown":
        ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Iconos/shutdown_On.png", UriKind.Relative));
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Con esto tu código debe funcionar sin problemas, por cierto, NO puedes hacer esto:

```
string miPicture = "campoImg";
miPicture.source = "./casa.png";
```

Por la simple razón de que `string miPicture` no tiene un `source` como le indicas en la linea que sigue.. y porqué? porque es un `string` y los `string` no tienen `source`.. simple.
Por eso te digo, lo que quieres setear es el `source` (origen) de `Image`, no del `Name` (nombre) de `Image`, **source** y **name** son atributos de **Image**, no los mezcles.

Un saludo.

Comment: Mil gracias por la información. Me ayudaste a entender unos conceptos que tenia liados....

Comment: De nada estimado, para eso estamos..

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar la imagen lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
miPicture.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri(".\Imagenes\casa.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

La ruta de la uri debe ser la que tengas tú en tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias.
Edite la pregunta para ser mas preciso.